# syntax error on python 3.x with variables

Tags: python

so I tried to list some variables and I keep getting a syntax error.

```
usr1 = 'boy'
usr2 = 'girl'
usr = input("What's your username: ")
if usr != usr1, usr2:
   print('Username not found, try again')
```

then I get an error

```
if usr != usr1, usr2:
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I also tried to remove the commas, same error, thanks

Comment: `if usr not in (usr1, usr2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't compare with two variables like that. You need to do two separate comparisons and combine them with a logical operation.

```
if usr != usr1 and usr != usr2:
```

Or you can put all your usernames in a collection:

```
valid_users = {usr1, usr2}
if usr not in valid_users:
```

Answer (score 0):

This snippet might solve your question

```py
usr1 = 'boy'
usr2 = 'girl'
usr = input("What's your username: ")
if usr != usr1 and usr != usr2:
    print('Username not found, try again')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
usr1 = 'boy'
usr2 = 'girl'
usr = input("What's your username: ")
if usr not in [usr1, usr2]:
   print('Username not found, try again')
```

Or you can use

```
usr1 = 'boy'
usr2 = 'girl'
usr = input("What's your username: ")
if usr!=usr1 and usr!=usr2:
   print('Username not found, try again')
```